# How do I change the quickix title (status bar) in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm have the following `makeprg` to compile my tex files in vim:

```
setlocal makeprg=pdflatex\ \-file\-line\-error\ \-shell\-escape\ \-interaction=nonstopmode\ $*\\\|\ tee\ \/dev\/tty\ \\\|\ grep\ \-P\ ':\\d{1,5}:\ '
```

which gives me good results (errors displayed properly, tex compilation shown while busy,...)

Yet there is one thing I'm not pleased off: when there are errors and the quickfix window pops up, its status bar is cluttered up with the makeprg string:

```
pdflatex\ \-file\-line\-error\ \-shell\-escape\ \-interaction=nonstopmode\ $*\\\|\ tee\ \/dev\/tty\ \\\|\ grep\ \-P\ ':\\d{1,5}:\ '
```

Is there a way of changing the quickfix title/statusbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little digging and experimentation revealed that the 'statusline' of a quickfix window is set to

```
%t%{exists('w:quickfix_title')? ' '.w:quickfix_title : ''}
```

Unfortunately, the w:quickfix_title variable isn't defined until some time after the quickfix buffer and window are created, so you can't use an autocommand to undefine (:unlet) or set the value of w:quickfix_title. However, you can use an autocommand to set the value of 'statusline', so putting this in your ~/.vimrc should fix the problem.

```
au BufWinEnter quickfix setl statusline=%t
```

Comment: I found this helpful, and used it to set a cleaner statusline.  Unfortunately when paging through earlier quickfix lists with `:colder` and `:cnewer` the ugly titles got restored again!  So I finally wrote this helper to preserve the cleaner statuslines: https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/commit/2011058c1a4e674e22364800eafdef1525f37ccf  I hope it may be useful to plugin authors!

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of vim have a ['title' field in the quickfix dictionary](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix-title):

> Every quickfix and location list has a title. By default the title is set to the command that created the list. The getqflist() and getloclist() functions can be used to get the title of a quickfix and a location list respectively. The setqflist() and setloclist() functions can be used to modify the title of a quickfix and location list respectively. Examples:
>
> ```
> call setqflist([], 'a', {'title' : 'Cmd output'})
> echo getqflist({'title' : 1})
> ```

Writing to this field clobbers `w:quickfix_title`, but not vice versa.

Modifications to the quickfix title with setqflist persist between `:colder`/`:cnewer`, so you could use an autocmd to clear them on initial load and they should keep that name for good:

```
autocmd QuickfixCmdPost * call setqflist([], 'a', {'title' : 'Quickfix Title'})
```